# Convert a list to another list in java

Tags: java

This is my problem:

```
private List<Package<Par<K, F>>> packages;

public void createPackages(List<Par<K, F>> entrys) {     
}
```

This is supposed to create packages from the entries list, each entry is a pair; each package will contain only entries with equal values to their first element.
Package and Par are other classes that I have.

If someone could help I would be really appreciate it.

Comment: What have you tried so far and what is the problem you face?

Comment: You should have provided your code for `Package` and `Par`, and show your effort and the issues.

Answer (score 2):

So basically what youre trying to do is pack everything in to this Package class if im not misunderstanding.

I assumed your Package class looking like this

```
public class Package<T>{
    List<T> a;
    public Package(List<T> a){
        this.a = a;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Packaged {" +a.toString() + "}";
    }
}
```

Or at least somewhat similar

then you should be able to convert your list like this

```
Map<Integer, List<Pair<Integer,Integer>>> test = l.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Pair::getKey));

List<Package<Pair<Integer,Integer>>> newList = test.values().stream().map(Package::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

i've tested this with the following code

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Pair<Integer,Integer>> l = new LinkedList<>();
        l.add(new Pair(1,1));
        l.add(new Pair(2,2));
        l.add(new Pair(2,3));
        System.out.println(l);
        Map<Integer, List<Pair<Integer,Integer>>> test = l.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Pair::getKey));
        List<Package<Pair<Integer,Integer>>> newList = test.values().stream().map(Package::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(newList);
    }
}
```

This gives the following output `[Packaged {[1=1]}, Packaged {[2=2, 2=3]}]`

What you're doing is basically calling `new Package(element)` for every `element` in your list. If you want special types of lists like converting between ArrayLists and LinkedList you can use `.collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new))` instead of toList.

Hope this answered your Question.
Cheers

For more information: https://www.baeldung.com/java-groupingby-collector